# Generic Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I want to create a set of extensions similiar to the .ToList<>() for a custom Generic Colletion I have.

Here are the Objects I have

```
AceDataObjectCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : IAceDataObject
IAceDataBlock : IAceDataObject
IAceMessage : IAceDataObject
```

I want to do this.

```
AceDataObjectCollection<IAceDataObject> objects = new AceDataObjectCollection<IAceDataObject>();
objects.Add(...)  // Add different data objects here
AceDataObjectCollection<IAceMessage> messages = objects.Where(o => o is IAceMessage).ToAceDataObjectCollection<IAceMessage>();
```

I can't seem to figure out how to form the extension properly with the generics.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you may be interested in the `OfType` LINQ method. So instead of your `Where` call, you could just say `.OfType<IAceMessage>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
public static AceDataObjectCollection<T> ToAceDataObjectCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col) where T : IAceDataObject 
{    
   AceDataObjectCollection<T> objects = new AceDataObjectCollection<T>();

   foreach (T item in col)
      objects.Add(item);

   return objects; 
}
```

Comment: This is exactlly what I needed.  I was missing the 'where T : IAceDataObject'  Portion.  Thanks very much.